# Is DBSet required for direct access?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I'm pretty sure I know the answer already, but I need it confirmed by others.
The question concerns the use of DbSet in Entity Framework: Code First. (Using C#)

Let's use these small classes as an example:

```
class TopClass
{
    Public List<ExampleA> ListOne {get; set;}
    Public List<ExampleB> ListTwo {get; set;}

    //Other contents ...
}

class ExampleA
{
    Public List<ExampleC> ListTree {get; set;}

    //Other contents ...
}

class ExampleB
{
    //Contents ...
}

class ExampleC
{
    //Contents ...
}
```

So TopClass has lists of the classes named ExampleA and ExampleB, and ExampleA has a list of ExampleC.

The class that inherits from DbContext could be like this:

```
class ExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TopClass> TopClasses {get; set}

    //Other contents..
}
```

Cuttently, there only DbSet is the one for the TopClass. Objects of Topclasses may be saved to a database, and objects of ExampleA, ExampleB and ExampleC that are put into the lists of the TopClass-objects / ExampleA-object, will also be saved into the database. If I load the TopClass-object from the database, all other objects that were in the lists will also be loaded. In other words, I have access to the other objects that have been saved to the databse through the object of the TopClass.

Now there is the question that I have been discussing with a collegue of mine:
If I want direct access to objects of ExampleA, without having to load the TopClass-object and all other related objects (and also without using SQL-coding or lambda-expression), do I need a DbSet for ExampleA? Or is it possible to reduce the loading from the DbSet to only include the objects that I want? If yes, is it even possible to load a object of ExampleA without loading TopClass?

I assume some of the answers are obvious. I myself believe one has to have a DbSet for direct access to objects of that class in the database, without having to load the TopClass-object. However, I need to know, not believe, so I ask of you to confirm or negate(?) my belief. As for what I've read so far on the Internet and somewhat in litterature, the use of DbSet for several classes emphazises to me effective coding, but not what is possible and not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following code exists:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TopClassMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExampleAMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExampleBMap());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ExampleCMap());
    // ....
}
```

you can access each using:

```
ExampleContext context = new ExampleContext();
var a = context.Set<TopClass>();
var b = context.Set<ExampleA>();
var c = context.Set<ExampleB>();
// etc
```

You do not need to declare a specific (or indeed any) `DbSet`'s